# Limit of $\lim_{t\to 1^+} \int_t^{t^2} \frac{\arctan(x)}{x-1} dx$

Tags: integration, limits

I need to evaluate $$\lim_{t\to 1^+} \int_t^{t^2} \frac{\arctan(x)}{x-1} \; dx.$$
I have tried the partial integrating, and I got confused. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Using mean value theorem write the expression under limit as $\arctan(c) \int_{t}^{t^2}(1/(x-1))\,dx$. As $t\to 1^{+}$ we have $c\to 1^{+}$ and the integral tends to $\log 2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\arctan(t^2)\ln(\frac{t^2-1}{t-1})\geq\int\limits_t^{t^2} \frac{\arctan(x)}{x-1}dx\geq\arctan(t)\ln(\frac{t^2-1}{t-1})$$
By squeeze theorem, the limit is $\frac{\pi}{4}\ln(2)$

Comment: (+1) for simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

Write $t = 1+\epsilon$ and notice that

\begin{align*}
\int_{t}^{t^2} \frac{\arctan x}{x-1} \, dx
&\stackrel{(x=1+\epsilon u)}{=} \int_{1}^{2+\epsilon} \frac{\arctan(1+\epsilon u)}{u} \, du \\
&\xrightarrow[\epsilon\downarrow0]{} \int_{1}^{2} \frac{\arctan(1)}{u} \, du
= \frac{\pi}{4}\log 2.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$artan (x) \to \frac {\pi} 4$ as $ x \to 1$. Hence the lmit  is $ \frac {\pi} 4 \lim \int_t^{t^{2}} \frac 1 {x-1} \, dt=(log \, 2 ) \frac {\pi} 4  $

Comment: This is implicit use of mean value theorem for integrals. +1

Comment: No. You can justify this using squeeze thoerm and explicit evaluation of the integral without the arctan part in term s of logarithms: $log (t^{2}-1) -log (t-1) =log (t+1) \to log \, 2$. My argument is essentially the one used by Jakobian.

Comment: Ok I thought you used $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) g(x) \, dx=f(c) \int_{a} ^{b} g(x) \, dx$ provided $g$ maintains constant sign.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{t \to 1^{\large +}}\int_{t}^{t^{2}}
{\arctan\pars{x} \over x - 1}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{t \to 1^{\large +}}\int_{t}^{t^{2}}
{\arctan\pars{x} - \arctan\pars{1} \over x - 1}\,\dd x\ +\
\lim_{t \to 1^{\large +}}\underbrace{\int_{t}^{t^{2}}
{\arctan\pars{1} \over x - 1}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{=\ {\pi \over 4}\,\ln\pars{t + 1}}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{\left.{\arctan\pars{x} - \arctan\pars{1} \over x - 1}
> \,\right\vert_{\ 1\ <\ t\ <\ x\ <\ t^{2}} =
> \left.{1 \over \xi^{2} + 1}
> \,\right\vert_{\ 1 <\ \xi\ <\ x}}$
>   
> $\ds{\implies
> \bbx{{1 \over x^{2} + 1} <
> \left.{\arctan\pars{x} - \arctan\pars{1} \over x - 1}
> \,\right\vert_{\ 1\ <\ t\ <\ x\ <\ t^{2}} < {1 \over 2}}}$

The first limit in \eqref{1} *vanishes out* because
$$
\arctan\pars{t^{2}} - \arctan\pars{t} <
\int_{t}^{t^{2}}
{\arctan\pars{x} - \arctan\pars{1} \over x - 1}\,\dd x <
{t\pars{t - 1} \over 2}
$$
such that \eqref{1} becomes
$$
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{t \to 1^{\large +}}\int_{t}^{t^{2}}
{\arctan\pars{x} \over x - 1}\,\dd x} =
\bbx{{\pi \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2}}
$$